# How to get count from database(table) and link to jsp page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have created 3 boxes represents "Booked", "Sold", and "Cancelled".
Now I want to get how many people that have been booked, sold, and cancelled order and put the number inside the boxes. Here is my jsp code:

```
 <table class = "btn1" align = "center"> 
<tr>
<th><button class = "book" onclick ="filterSelection('Booked')">Booked</button><% %></th>
<th><button class = "sold" onclick ="filterSelection('Sold')"> Sold </button></th>
<th><button class = "cancel" onclick ="filterSelection('Cancelled')"> Cancelled </button></th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And mysql is:

```
public String getStatus2 (String co_no, String projCde, String solcCde, String phaseNum, Date cur_date) throws SQLException {
System.out.println("/*** Lot Status **");
String status1="";
     String sql5= "SELECT\r\n" + 
            "    COUNT(CASE WHEN smu_sts_cde = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS booked_cnt,\r\n" + 
            "    COUNT(CASE WHEN smu_sts_cde = 'S' THEN 1 END) AS sold_cnt,\r\n" + 
            "    COUNT(CASE WHEN smu_sts_cde = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS cancelled_cnt\r\n" + 
            "FROM smpurl\r\n" 
            +"WHERE\r\n" 
            +"    smu__book_dte <=  '"+cur_date+"'"  
            +"    smu_proj_cde = '"+projCde+"'" 
            +"    smu_phase_num = '"+phaseNum+"'" 
            +"    smu_buyr_solc_cde = '"+solcCde+"'";
     String lotCde = super.execStr(sql5,false);
     System.out.println("Execute = " +sql5);
     System.out.println("Execute = " +lotCde);
     if(lotCde != "") {
         String sql6 = "SELECT count(*) FROM smpurl"
                    + " WHERE smu_sts_cde = '"+lotCde+"'"; 
         System.out.println("Execute = " + sql6);
         String lotNme = super.execStr(sql6,false);
         status1 = lotNme;
     }else {
         status1 = "BOOKED";
        }
```

How can I get the number inside my jsp page?

Comment: Please include the full Java code which is executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

For a partial answer, covering your MySQL requirement, you should be using conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN smu_sts_cde = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS booked_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN smu_sts_cde = 'S' THEN 1 END) AS sold_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN smu_sts_cde = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS cancelled_cnt
FROM smpurl
WHERE
    smu__book_dte <= ? AND
    smu_proj_cde = ?   AND
    smu_phase_num = ?  AND
    smu_buyr_solc_cde = ?;
```

The `?` placeholders are what represent the various dynamic values you want to use in the `WHERE` clause.  Ideally, you would be using some sort of prepared statement.  The various counts would be available using the aliases I have defined for them.